# SQL update and insert

Tags: sql, sql-update

I want to do this

```
UPDATE CATALOGUE 
SET CATALOGUE.NUMBERINSTOCK=NUMBERINSTOCK-1 
WHERE CATALOGUE.ITEMID =(SELECT ALBUM.ALBUM_ID 
                         FROM ALBUM 
                         WHERE ALBUM.TITLE = '20 People in a Field'
                              AND IS_DISTRIBUTED_AS ='c')
```

and this

```
INSERT INTO ORDERELEMENT VALUES (1,10,12,17)
```

if this is true

```
(SELECT NUMBERINSTOCK 
 FROM CATALOGUE 
 WHERE CATALOGUE.ITEMID =(SELECT ALBUM.ALBUM_ID 
                          FROM ALBUM 
                          WHERE ALBUM.TITLE = '20 People in a Field'
                                   AND IS_DISTRIBUTED_AS ='c')) > 0
```

The problem I have is finding how to do a conditional statement in an SQL query, and also how to do an update and insert as part of one query.

I must do all these things as one query.

Comment: i am doing a databases course and this is part of one of the questions i found the rest ok but every way i try this problem i get errors :(

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can't update one table and insert into another table in one statement.
It is possible to conditionally perform an UPDATE if you specify a WHERE clause. You can acomplish the same thing with insert (details depends on dbms).

You can however create a stored procedure that contains your conditional logic. The invokation of that procedure might count as "one" statement?

Comment: In PostgreSQL you *can* update one table and insert into another in a single statement. It's called "writeable CTE" and I think SQL Server supports that as well.